# error C2995: 'getVector' : template function has already been defined

Tags: c++

I am using VC 6.0 and While compiling the code i am getting this error "error C2995: 'getVector' : template function has already been defined"

I have included the value of WIN32COMMON in the project Settings->C++ tab and in the
category combo box as Preprocessor and in the preprocessordefinition text box as  _WIN32COMMON and in the Addition include Libraries  text box the complete path as "E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1\OCI\include". in this include folder all the header files are present such as "occi.h".

I also tried with defining WIN32COMMON in my code Explicitly as  follows

```
#include<iostream>
#define WIN32COMMON
#include <occi.h>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;
```

but then it started me giving 102 errors stating that 'DbManager undeclared identifier'.

i had also tried with including the addition libraries in the project settings->link tab->
and in category combobox i selected Input and in the Additional library path i gave the complete path for .lib files as "E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1\OCI\lib\MSVC\vc8" but that also did'nt work. can somebody please guide me.Where iam lacking or i need to define some thing else in my code.

Comment: VS 2006?? Should that be 2005? 2008?

Comment: Iam very srry! i forgot to mention it is vc++ 6.0. by mistake i wrote 2006.

Comment: Just an idea: don't add `using namespace ..;`, just use the full named version of the functions!

Answer (score 0):

MSVC++ 6.0 doesn't support partial ordering of function templates. Try to replace `getVector()` with `getVectorOfRefs()` in your code.

Oracle added `getVectorOfRefs()` into OCCI to support older Microsoft compilers, such as MSVC6, and recommends to use it in place of `getVector()`.

Comment: Do you mean that i should replace getvector() function from occicontrol.h to getvectorofrefs(). Because i have not included any getvector() function in my code ! i cn show you my code as well! its just a simple code of connecting to oracle! i have never done database connection through c++.

Comment: Any one can please tell me step by step process what is missing in my code or in visual studio 6.0, So that i can connect to my database! below is the code that i have written.

Comment: Yes, it's better if you show the code - a minimal piece of code that doesn't compile.